# Parsing Complex JSON in Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

Dears - I'm using ADF to parse output of a REST API that is coming in JSON structure.
The problem is that JSON contains array of strings, each string value contains JSON object.
I want to extract the values of the innermost JSON .. I've tried several attempts with no luck yet..

> Sample JSON Structure

```
  {
    "tables": [
      {
        "name": "PrimaryResult",
        ,
        "rows": [
          ["{\"Subscription Name\":\"master\",\"Operation Name\":\"5f2a763e4f5cabb8d38dd66a\",... \"}","other nested JSON".....
```

I'm not able to parse those JSONs that are coming as strings surrounded by double quotes.

any ideas ??

Comment: If you are frustrated with ADF's pure lack of multi-collection selection when it comes to parsing JSON, Please upvote this: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/23432697-7026-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#json) function to change JSON string to JSON object.

My test:

Output of Web activity
[image]

Use this expression to get value of `Subscription Name`:

```
@json(activity('Web1').output.tables[0].rows[0][0])['Subscription Name']
```

Output of Set variable activity:

[image]

**Update**

I'm not sure what you need. It seems you want to change all JSON string to JSON object.

If so, you can create an array variable, loop `rows[0]` by For Each activity and transform items to JSON object in a new array.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That works fine. But I need to pass the whole inner JSON to another activity (e.g., Copy) to break it down and save values in Database columns.. what should I do ? Considering that the JSON contains further nested arrays. Please advise ..

Comment: @user9942114 I update my answer. Is that you need?

Comment: that approach will not enable me to perform nested loops nor write parsed data to files .. Please advise ..

Comment: Please show me screenshot of your pipeline and tell me  all your need.

Comment: @mamhh, assuming you want to do something similar to what I did:

replace the foreach  "items" box @activity('Get List of Tables').output.tables[0].rows[0] with @activity('Get List of Tables').output.tables[0].rows this ill iterate over the rows. 

Then, replace @json(item()) with @item()[0]. This will retrieve the first item in each row.